# Are there any numerical packages solving Volterra integral equations?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I am looking for numerical packages (ideally python) to solve second kind Volterra integral equations, such as

$$u(t)=g(t)+\int_0^tK(t,s)u(s) ds$$

or Volterra-Fredholm integral equations

$$u(x,t)=g(t,x)+c\int_0^t\int_\Omega K(t,s,x,\xi)u(s,\xi) d\xi ds$$

Are there any callable functions in python to solve such equations? if not, are there any standard algorithm to solve such equations?  Thanks.

Comment: Check [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/search.pl?query=volterra). You might also want to ask at [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can't go wrong if you follow [Numerical Recipes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Recipes) Chapter 18.2 has the code for the Volterra integral equation of the second kind. Here is the [book itself](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c18-2.pdf), there may also be downloadable code online.

Comment: One should take care when using Numerical Recipes, particularly if you are considering distributing the resulting code at some point. http://numerical.recipes/licenses/

Comment: @J.J.Green. Indeed. With the current ideas of copyright I'll soon be put in jail for making scrambled eggs for breakfast without purchasing a proper license from the cookbook publishers. The code for VE in NR is not bad, but nothing really surprising or far superior to any homemade  contraption of the type "just break the eggshells and pour what's inside on a moderately hot pan".